# How to prove the the spectral radius is positive and the associated eigenvector has positive components?

Tags: matrices, spectral-theory

For strictly lower and upper triangular matrices $L$ and $U$, let $B=L+U$ be a nonnegative and irreducible $n\times n$ matrix. Prove that the spectral radius of matrix $H=(I-L)^{-1}U$ is positive and that its associated eigenvector has positive components?

Since the matrix $L$ is strictly lower triangular matrix, it can be proved that the matrix $H$ is also nonnegative matrix. They there exists a nonnegative vector $x\geq 0$ such that $Hx=\lambda x$, where $\lambda=\rho(H)\geq 0$. But the problem is how to use the nonnegative and irreducible character of matrix $B$ to show $\lambda$ and $x$ are both positive？

Comment: Since $U$ is "strictly... upper triangular", it is singular, and hence $H = (I-L)^{-1}U$ is singular as well.  So you need something more than just the fact that $Hx = \lambda x$ to conclude $\lambda \gt 0$.

Comment: You are right. The thing we need is the irreduciblr character of matrix $B$, but I wonder how to use  the property of matrix $B$ to get that $\rho(H)>0$ and the corresponding eigenvector is also positive?